# Como imprimir corretamente a seguinte expressão? Math.pow (2, (1/12));

Tags: java

A expressão `2^(1/12)` deveria apresentar o resultado: `1,0594630943593`.
Mas quando aplico na função Math.pow o resultado só dá `1.0`. Alguém poderia me ajudar e dizer como faço para imprimir o valor correto?

Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
double x = Math.pow(2, (1/12));
System.out.println(x);
SAÍDA: 1.0
```

Comment: 1/12 é uma divisão de inteiros e o resultado é um inteiro. Tente 1.0/12.

Comment: É verdade. Não me atentei para este fato. 
Muito Obrigado!